# How can I show different headers for custom post type drop down template in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a Custom post type called `cme-education` which has a drop down to select a custom post type template (similarly how you would with a page template drop down for pages in wordpress). When I select the template, it works however, I want to be able to show a different header for that template but I am not sure how to achieve that.

my code for the drop down CPT template is in
**template-in-conversation.php file**

```
<?php
/*
 Template Name: IN CONVERSATION 
 Template Post Type: cme-education
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
```

and then I have a header file which has an if statement to show the associated headers based on the condition
**header.php file**

```
 if(is_singular('in-conversation')){
        get_template_part('includes/headers/header_in_convo'); 
    } else {
        echo "not found";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a custom header file for that like `header-in_convo.php`.

Then you could do this:

```
if(is_singular('in-conversation')){
    get_header( 'in_convo' );
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
```

See [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/)

Comment: this did not work so I ended up using `
if(is_page_template('templates/template-in-conversation.php')){
        get_template_part('includes/headers/header_in_convo'); 
    }